# How to add rpath $ORIGIN to native executable for android cross build

Tags: android, cmake

I am trying to build an executable for Android with cross compiling, everything works but the executable complains that it could not find the .so file it needs, which is in the same directory as the executable.
So what I did is to add the following lines

```
set(TARGET myapp)

# following 4 lines added to add RPATH of ./ to the binary
# so it searches the .so in the same directory
SET(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH FALSE)
SET(CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH FALSE)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH $ORIGIN)
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH ON)

# add source code to target
add_executable(${TARGET} src.cpp)
...
```

However, it builds the executable, but `RPATH` seems not working no matter how I play with the four lines above, I just could not find any `RPATH` info in the binary using `readelf` or `objdump`.
I also tried `set_target_properties(${TARGET} PROPERTIES INSTALL_RPATH $ORIGIN)` but still not working.

Did I miss use anything here for `RPATH` configuration?

**update**
just to note that if I build the app for host(Linux) (using the same cmake file except using the android ndk tool chain) then everything is fine, I see `$ORIGIN` in the binary `RPATH` using `readelf`.
although i dont know what is been done in android ndk tool chain

Answer (score 0):

**This is probably not what you want:**
(I am mentioning it just to be complete with my answer)

I assume that `$ORIGIN` is an environment variable. If that is the case you need to explain to `CMake` that it is such an variable. You can use `$ENV{VAR}` to do this, e.g.:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH $ENV{ORIGIN})
```

---

**This is probably what you want:**

Ofcourse if the variable is not accessible during CMake generation step. You can try to use bracket arguments, however I do not think that alone would work (see last note at the bottom). Bracket arguments `[=[...]=]` tell CMake to skip the evaluation, because `$` is a special character. e.g.:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH [=[$ORIGIN]=])
```

To understand what `[=[]=]` do here is a simple example:

```
set(FOO "bar")
message(STATUS ${FOO})
message(STATUS [=[${FOO}]=])
```

Should output

```
bar
${FOO} #<-- evaluation of ${FOO} was skipped
```

Also if I'm not mistaken you also need to pass `$ORIGIN` to linker with single quotes so that it doesn't get evaluated during linking, i.e.

```
'$ORIGIN'
#and not $ORIGIN
```

Comment: not sure if i get it but why i still need to pass $ORIGIN to linker if i already set it in cmake? also i dont think the issue is how i put $ORIGIN 'cus this is something recommended and tested by someone else. ...

Comment: `$ORIGIN` is passed to the linker by CMake, but you want it to pass `rpath='$ORIGIN'` and not `rpath=$ORIGIN` that's what I'm explaining here. Because in the latter it will get evaluated during the build/linking phase. But what you want is to be evaluated when your binary uses the `rpath` to find the needed libraries.  CMake is just a tool that configures the compiler/linker for you so when I say that you are configuring the linker you are doing so by using CMake.

Comment: @shelper Maybe to just clarify once more, **I'm not saying** that you need to pass it to the linker and set it in CMake. **I am saying** that you are passing the linker option via CMake.

Comment: it just doesn't work for android ndk... see my updated question, thanks for the help anyway...

Comment: @shelper interesting, do you think you can debug this further by generating the cmake file (with the NDK toolchain) and then greping all files for 'rpath' just to see what it passes? I.e. `grep -rinw '/path/to/buildfolder' -e 'rpath'` - just to debug what it inputs during the build process.

Comment: I just noticed. You alway have to use the NDK toolchain if I'm not mistaken. It contains all the specific linker/compiler configurations and environment variables that are needed to build the binaries properly.